# Save Image Into Database using api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a web application with many layers (DAL, BLL, SL, UI), each layer in a separate project.

I am consuming a Web API in the presentation layer (UI) using ajax, where I am using single page application.

Example: in index action in home controller in the presentation layer(UI) only refers to view:

```
public class MaCityController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Mainten/MasterFile/MaCity/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

and in this view I am doing my CRUD operation using Web API and Ajax:

```
function Add() {     
        var NameAr = $('#NameAr').val();
        var NameEn = $('#NameEn').val();
        var Image = $('#FileName').val();
        var newData = new Object();

        newData.NameAr = NameAr;
        newData.NameEn = NameEn;
        newData.Image=Image;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: APIURL + "api/MaCity/Add",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(newData),
            success: function () {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                debugger;
                loadData();

            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.statusText);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.statusText);
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

My posting code in Sl as

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add(City scItem)
{
        _unitOfWork.GetRepository<City>().Add(scItem);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
}
```

Where api In another Application with different port than presentation Layer (UI)
and any dealing with database occurs in SL (NO DEAL WITH DATA IN UI).

I need to upload an image to the server and save (image server url) into the database.

I read many articles but I can't find solution to solve my problem.

Any help?

Comment: Do you have anything to show on the server side? For exmaple your current api endpoint, that does not work, so we can help you?

Comment: Can you post your API code too.

Comment: @KiranJoshi Done, But save Image not completed yet.

Comment: @Marco i not yet try any thing i update poet and add code in sl layer ,i can't find way satisfy my problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking if the file is getting added to the json request object? there are a few ways you can try this, e.g using a tool like Telerik Fiddler

inside your json post method, check if there are any files in your form

```
 var file =$(this).prop('files')[0];
```

A somewhat example would be the following

add the image to FormData

```
formdata = new FormData();
    if($(this).prop('files').length > 0)
    {
        var file =$(this).prop('files')[0];
        formdata.append("image", file);
    }
```

Then finally post the post the image

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "api_path,
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (result) {
         // if all is well
         // play the audio file
    }
});
```

You can also try sending the data from your Controller(assuming you are using some MVC flavour)